# Second Call to Ajax get the First Result Allways

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax

I Using this code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('#DoTask').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault(); // added this
        $.getJSON('/TareasBackGround/DoTaskInteractivo', null,
                function(response) {
                    $('#ResultadoEjecutarTarea').html("<br />Resutado:" + response.result);
                    $('#ResultadoEjecutarTarea').css("style", "");


                });
    });
});
```

After the first call I get always the same result. I add the time stamp to the result to check this.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this:

```
$.ajaxSetup ({cache: false});
```

right above your click event.  This should prevent the ajax request from caching.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably caching the result the first time, so when you request it the second time you get the same (cached) timestamp.

Answer (score 1):

The response is probably cached. You can set the Ajax [option](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.ajax#options) cache to false or add a timestamp at the request:

```
currentTime= (new Date()).getTime();    
url = '/TareasBackGround/DoTaskInteractivo?_=' + currentTime;
```

Comment: I try the '/TareasBackGround/DoTaskInteractivo?_=[current time in millis here]' like this '/TareasBackGround/DoTaskInteractivo?_=<%= DateTime.Now.Millisecond %>' Get the same behavior.

Comment: You need to re-calculate the current time at the client, not just once at the server.